# Set ALB's DNS name for aws-alb-ingress-controller

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am implementing an ingress controller with AWS and following [this](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller/blob/master/docs/walkthrough.md) tutorial.

When creating an ingress as shown [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller/master/examples/echoservice/echoserver-ingress.yaml), a  host name should be given.

```
spec:
  rules:
  - host: echoserver.example.com #How to let kubernate assign ALB's DNS name and not give our own DNS name.
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: echoserver
          servicePort: 80
```

But I want to give the ALB's generated DNS name as I don't have my own DNS name. Is there any way to do it ? I tried ommiting the **host** attribute. But when I describe the ingress as mentioned in my tutorial mentioned above (section 13) running

```
 kubectl describe ing -n echoserver echoserver
```

The value of Address in the response of above command is empty, therefore no way to hit the ingress.

*UPDATE*:

I created a ALB (through the aws UI, and allowed to forward requests to a target group which is created as default) and set its DNS name to the host name(in simple letters) in ingress yaml file. But I can't see it works. I follow the steps mentioned in above [above tutorial](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller/blob/master/docs/walkthrough.md).

```
kubectl logs -n kube-system \
    $(kubectl get po -n kube-system | \
    egrep -o alb-ingress[a-zA-Z0-9-]+) | \
    egrep -o '\[ALB-INGRESS.*$'
```

When the above log command executed only the following output returned:

```
[ALB-INGRESS] [controller] [INFO]: Log level read as "", defaulting to INFO. To change, set LOG_LEVEL environment variable to WARN, ERROR, or DEBUG.
[ALB-INGRESS] [controller] [INFO]: Ingress class set to alb
[ALB-INGRESS] [controller] [INFO]: albNamePrefix undefined, defaulting to f0591ff6
```

As per step 12, when the log command executed,

```
kubectl logs -n kube-system \
    $(kubectl get po -n kube-system | \
    egrep -o alb-ingress[a-zA-Z0-9-]+) | \
    egrep -o '\[ALB-INGRESS.*$' | \
    grep 'echoserver\/echoserver'
```

there is no any logs.

Also, when following command executed:
kubectl describe ing -n echoserver echoserver
The response is:

```
Name:             echoserver
Namespace:        echoserver
Address:
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (172.17.0.4:8080)
Rules:
  Host                                                Path  Backends
  ----                                                ----  --------
  ingress-alb-3455057285.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com
                                                      /   echoserver:80 ()
Annotations:
Events:
```

Any idea please where things go wrong ?
I did not set any IAM roles here. If it is required, let me know how should I do it.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to use ingresses like this, ingresses expect a DNS name as they need to be able to route traffic.

You can get around this by simply editing your hosts file for a bit of a hack:

```
my_fake_dns <ip_of_alb>
```

You might want to try using a [Service of type LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/), which automatically generate an ELB (not an ALB) or an [NLB](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/network-load-balancer-support-in-kubernetes-1-9/) for you.

Answer (score 2):

It would be quite easy to create a shell script that does the following:

1. Describe your AWS load balancer

   [ELBv1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elb/describe-load-balancers.html)

   ```
   aws elb describe-load-balancers --load-balancer-name my-load-balancer
   ```

   [ELBv2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/describe-load-balancers.html)

   ```
   aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers --load-balancer-arns arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-2:123456789012:loadbalancer/app/my-load-balancer/50dc6c495c0c9188
   ```
2. Filter LB DNS name from the step 1 output:

   ELBv1

   ```
   jq '.LoadBalancerDescriptions[].DNSName'
   ```

   ELBv2

   ```
   jq '.LoadBalancers[].DNSName'
   ```
3. Insert results from the step 3 to your ingress yaml template file
4. Apply resulting YAML file from the step 4 to your cluster.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I understand is that I should create an ALB in advance and get the DNS name and then use that DNS name into my Ingress.Am I correct ? If it is so, will kubernates will detect my ALB and work together ?

Comment: Yes, you can create LB and use it's name in Ingress. Remember to add that name to certificate when you setup https. Kubernetes do nothing with LB created by someone else. It works fine if LB forwards traffic to Kubernetes node(s) and Kubernetes is configured correctly to forward this traffic to pod(s). Kubernetes can create and configure LB on cloud for Service(type LoadBalancer) and for Ingress controller only if it is supported by cloud provider. Kubernetes supports creating cloud LB on GCP, AWS, Azure, not sure about others.

Comment: The DNS name of the ALB cannot be used. if used, following error is thrown: 

The Ingress "echoserver" is invalid: spec.rules[0].host: Invalid value: "Ingress-ALB-1935054365.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com": a DNS-1123 subdomain must consist of lower case alphanumeric charact        ers, '-' or '.', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'example.com', regex used for validation is '[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?)*')

Comment: You may need to transform it to lowercase then. DNS service is case-insensitive by design.

Comment: I updated my question with what I have done so far. Would you have a look under the *UPDATE* in my question. Thanks

Comment: May be I misunderstood something, but if you deploy alb-ingress-controller, it should create ALB based on your ingress objects. So you don't need to create ALB by hand. My answer was more suited for manually created NLB or ELB and manually configured nginx-ingress controller. Try to delete manually created LB, check state of deployment alb-ingress-controller and redeploy Ingress object for echoservice. Try also increase log level by setting set LOG_LEVEL environment variable to WARN, ERROR, or DEBUG.